# LINQ2SQL entity constructor constraints

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm

L2SQL generates entities with a default a parameterless constructor. This CANNOT be changed as it is needed to materialise the object.

However, if my object can only be created with certain values initialised how would I go about hiding the parameterless constructor so that a consumer only sees a constructor with parameters?

**1)** I can create another partial class of the same name and add my new constructor there but the consumer now simply has two options to create an instance of my class. The parameterless constructor is still visible.

**2)** Use interfaces. It is not possible to create an interface that defines constructors.

How do people approach this as it looks like an issue that would occur a lot.

Comment: Yet another case where the supplied code generation tools for linq-to-sql doesn't stand up to the true power of L2S. It really feels like Microsoft want everybody to go away from L2S.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent other users of the class from constructing one from the parameterless constructor, but still allow Linq2SQL to use it (as it must do so).

Luckily you are wrong when you say the default parameterless constructor cannot be changed. If you change the constructor of a Linq2SQL entity class to be private, then it will still be called by Linq2SQL as it uses reflection, and it is possible to call a private constructor if you use reflection. (Incidentally, other changes to the constructor can also be done with Linq2SQL).

Of course, the other users of the class can also use reflection to call that private constructor and create a class in a private state, but that is true of all .NET classes (and indeed applies elsewhere - e.g. it's often not hard to usurp the privacy of C++ classes, though there is no implementation-independent guarantee either way). But then it's pretty much always possible to use reflection to mess a class up; encapsulation is a mechanism to ensure correctness, not security. (But security restrictions on what code can use reflection then builds security on top of that less guarantee).

Comment: Is it possible to change the default ctor generated by the graphical ORM-designer or SqlMetal to private or does it require manual coding of the entity classes?

Comment: I've never used them, so I don't know. You could of course use them as a starting point, and then manually edit the output. The disadvantage would be that you can't rebuild from them again, but if you are making these classes visible to other code then you can't rebuild from them again anyway, as that could bring about breaking changes that stopped that other code from working.

Comment: That worked a treat Jon. I never thought of changing the access modifier of the L2S generated entity as I thought L2S had set the level of accessibility on those entities that it needed to do its underlying operations. The L2S generated comments put me off changing too! ie // Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated. - The regenerating I can cope with. Cheers

Comment: NP. If it worked for you, can you accept the answer? (And vote it up too, though IIRC you need more reputation points to do that). That marks it as having solved your problem, and helps someone coming along with a similar problem quickly see that this is a useful answer rather than a red-herring.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't actually get this to work. I edited my business/ORM assembly and marked a sample Customer entity's constructor as private and then added a public constructor with parameters to another partial class of the same name (separate business logic). However once my presentation layer consumed the business/ORM assembly and tried to add a new customer an error was thrown at myDataContext.SubmitChanges(); ArgumentNullException, Value cannot be null Parameter name: cons - It looks like L2S is having difficult materialising the Customer object due to the new private access modifier

Comment: I also tried marking the parameterless constructor as internal but no joy there. The only way I can get the object I create via the parameterised constructor to be added via myDataContext.SubmitChanges(); is if there is an accompanying parameterless constructor with a public access modifier for that entity. There must be some way L2S users are approaching this problem. It seems a real drawback of the ORM tool.

Comment: Confirmed same constructor access modifier requirement for entities generated with sqlmetal - used /code flag ie .cs output, not .dbml